# Hungry, hungry _____

Tags: riddle

Be kind, this is my first time trying to make my own...

> When my owner is closed, I am open
>
> My owner never cleans me out
>
> Few can afford to keep me fed
>
> Because people always take my food

What am I?

Comment: why the downvote?  Way to promote others making riddles... no explanation of downvote.

Comment: To be honest, the Puzzling.SE community hasn't decided whether riddles are on-topic or not and if they are, what makes a good riddle. Until we've come to a consensus, I think riddles are likely to attract both a lot of upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: See this meta thread for more information: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46/so-whats-our-actual-stance-on-riddles

Comment: fair enough, but a downvote without comment is bad practice all over SO. Guess it is just me, but every time I think of puzzles I think of riddles...

Comment: @KisnardOnline Whatever one may think of commentless downvoting, comments asking "why the downvote?" aren't exactly seen as good practice, either. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74559/212780

Comment: without 'commentless downvoting' those questions are out of the realm of possibility, aren't they?

Comment: They're noise and a bit pointless. Downvotes(and voting in general) are *not* noise, but the main way we have of sorting the good content from the bad. Feel free to disagree, but nobody should feel *obligated* to comment every time they vote.

Comment: That meta post is a mixed bag(many agree and disagree with you). If someone downvoted and commented 'riddles are (potentially) not allowed here' it would make things clear - and hopefully stop riddles.  I don't think that is refutable.  That all being said, I came to Puzzling for fun, not nonsense... answer my riddle.

Comment: @KisnardOnline You're assuming that's the reason, though. It could just be they're having a bad day, or just don't like this for some reason. People vote for all kinds of dumb reasons, and sometimes the explanation simply wouldn't be helpful. Also, there is not much of a mixed bag there. Both *answers* (posted by SE staff, incidentally) say they are noise. There are commentors disagreeing, but nobody cared enough to write an opposing answer, whereas the existing answers are voted up far more than down.

Comment: But if I knew the answer to your riddle, I'd answer it ;)

Comment: I downvoted because the answer given by Kevin seemed to me to totally fit the riddle, but is not the correct answer, indicating that the riddle is ambiguous.

Comment: @xnor I gotta disagree about that answer fitting the clue :p

Comment: God I hope the answer is good... I've been trying to crack it all day :(

Comment: I think this riddle had a good idea, but just not enough clues to specify the desired answer uniquely. Most of the clues point towards a single aspect of the answer, so one can justify alternatives that share that aspect. I'd suggesting adding another stanza that hints at other properties.

Comment: @Kevin -  I'm finding it hard to know what the puzzling community (doesn't that include people who like riddles?)  actually thinks qualifies as a puzzle. If you/we/they? keep banning things, where will it end? Probably by people leaving.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica In the time since I left that comment in 2014, I believe that this community has decided that riddles are on topic.

Comment: @Kevin - Oh good - Don't know how I got here without noticing it was an old thread!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A variant of Damien's answer:

> an ATM machine.

*When my owner is closed, I am open*

> When the bank is closed, the ATM machine is still open.

*My owner never cleans me out*

> The bank never empties their ATM machines.

*Few can afford to keep me fed*

> Not many people have enough money to supply an ATM machine.

*Because people always take my food*

> People are withdrawing money from it all the time.

Credit to @AeJey for this answer. He didn't think it worked, but it seems to me to fit all the clues. ("When", not "when and only when", in the first line!)

Comment: YESSSS!!! you got it.  See riddles can be fun! :)  And that was 100% made up by me - so there was no way to solve on google.  Was it fun?  If so I may tell my family haha.

Comment: @KisnardOnline gg all :) welcome to puzzling :D

Comment: @KisnardOnline - Yes, good riddle! :-)

Comment: @AeJey - sorry I pinched your idea :-(

Answer (score 8):

I believe it to be

> a vending machine.

'When my owner is closed, I am open'

> Doesn't matter what time of day it is, the vending machine will happily take your money.

'My owner never cleans me out'

> Customers clean out vending machines - the owner never need to.

'Few can afford to keep me fed'

> Either a comment on the inflated prices you pay for the convenience, or the fact that it's only businesses which can justify the cost of purchase and stocking.

'Because people always take my food'

> The purpose of a vending machine - to dispense tasty goodness.

Comment: it is close, but some dont link as perfectly as they do with another clue... see answer just marked.  You do get credit for inspiring @rand al'thor

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> An account

When my owner is closed, I am open

> The "owner" is the customer. When a bank "closes" a client the account is "opened".

My owner never cleans me out

> The customer will never rob himself.

Few can afford to keep me fed

> Not many people can keep their account topped up...

Because people always take my food

> Money is always required to the spent.

Comment: verrry close but some people do close accounts... I have done it before.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> one of the hippos from the game [Hungry Hungry Hippos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungry_Hungry_Hippos).

The answer fits the title, "Hungry Hungry _____."

> When my owner is closed, I am open

When you press the lever for your hippo closed, the hippo opens its mouth.

> My owner never cleans me out

In the middle of a game of HHH, you don't empty the tray of pellets you've grabbed.

> Few can afford to keep me fed
>
> Because people always take my food

You're competing against three other people trying to eat pellets, making it difficult to grab the most pellets.

Comment: lateral thinking... the first one is a stretch.. second one does not fit at all.. NEVER

Comment: Really? I seriously thought this was the correct answer xD

Comment: haha too obvious or I would not have titled it like that :D  to be honest when I made that title I was thinking of the game a little bit :)